# Pivot Table does not refresh automatically after refreshing the OLAP cube. Excel 2007

Tags: excel, olap, pivot-table

I have a workbook connected to an external OLAP cube.  Previously, when I connected to the external data source and then refreshed all, every pivot table would refresh and show the new data.  Now, if I connect to the data source and refresh the pivots, the pivots do not update with new data.  The only way I can get it to update is if I manually click in one of my filters then click ok.  For some reason, this triggers a connection to the cube and the pivot refreshes with the new data.  Any idea why this might be happening?  I'm at a loss and it's extremely time consuming to have to manually click in each pivot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by making my own refresh button that just sends simple queries to the cube for each pivot I wanted to be refreshed and that solved the issue.